# How SQL selects between two strings/texts?

Tags: sql, linq, select

In SQL if I've the following select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductName BETWEEN 'Geitost' AND 'Pavlova'
```

It run successfully and display the output records, but I'm a little bit confusing about how we can search between two strings and how the SQL perform it,

for example the following select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Price BETWEEN 100 AND 300
```

It's clear that we are trying to find all the prices which has a price equals to 100$ or greater but less than or equals 300$

Can somebody explain what is the selecting mechanism between two strings in SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Details are DBMS specific but think about how you would search for names between 'Geitost' and 'Pavlova' in a phone book.

Comment: "but think about how you would search for names between 'Geitost' and 'Pavlova' in a phone book." It's a brilliant idea to imagine how to figure out it, Thanks a lot.
This means that the words 'Geitoss' and 'Pavlovb' will be excluded while the words 'Hockey',  'Stars' and even 'Pavlovaa' will be included.

Comment: I would expect 'Stars' and 'Pavlovaa' to be excluded because both are alphabetically after 'Pavlova', not between the values.

Comment: Sorry, your'e right it will be excluded. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather baffling. This code works:

```
WHERE Price BETWEEN 100 AND 300
```

It is turned into:

```
WHERE Price >= 100 AND Price <= 300
```

Similarly, your first condition is equivalent to:

```
WHERE ProductName >= 'Geitost' AND
      ProductName <= 'Pavlova'
```

So the question is about how strings are compared. The short answer is "how they appear in the dictionary". Of course, there are lots of dictionaries in the world. The more complete answer is based on *collations*, which describe the alphabetic ordering of strings.

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html) is the MySQL documentation for collations and character sets. Although some details such as the names of the collations and the syntax for functions may vary, the idea is similar across databases.